# Type Error when replacing values in a dataframe

Tags: python

TypeError: Cannot compare types `'ndarray(dtype=float64)'` and `'tuple'`

I have tried different astypes but nothing seems to be working

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,4))
y = data.mean()
print (y)
z = stats.zscore(data)
# print(z)

threshold = 3
a = pd.DataFrame(np.where(z > 3)).astype('float64')
print(a.dtypes)

b = pd.DataFrame(a.mean()).T.astype('float64')
print(b.dtypes)

a.replace(to_replace = [np.where(z > 3)], value = b).astype('float64')
print(a)
```

I hope to get the `z score values > 3` replaced with the mean of the outliers

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following solution with the final output z where `z score values > 3` is replaced with the mean of the outliers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4))
print (data)  # 4x4

z = stats.zscore(data)
print(z)  # 4x4

threshold = 1

# Outliers that is a subset of z having value > threshold
a = z[np.where(z > threshold)]
print(a)  # 1xn (n may vary)

# Mean of a which is a scalar value
b = a.mean()
print(b)  # scalar value

# Updating the outliers of z with outliers mean
z = np.where(z > 3, b, z)
print(z)  # 4x4 same size as z
```